# sed not replacing a full sentence

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed

`ssh root@$IP sed -i -e 's/listen\t80\default_server;/test/' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` is there something I am not doing correctly?

I am doing to learn how to use sed - but I think the greatest route for making a general configuration across multiple server is to upload the conf file? Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's your problem now? Getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are missing a tab:

```
 listen\t80\tdefault_server
```

If it was me, I'd replace the tab pattern with general whitespace pattern to allow a little flexibility:

```
 listen\s\+80\s\+default_server
```

or

```
 listen[[:space:]]\+80[[:space:]]\+default_server
```

Comment: ssh root@$IP sed -i -e 's/listen\s\+80\s\+default_server;/test/' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

would this be correct?

Comment: I would try the sed command directly on the remote server to ensure it works before embedding it into an ssh command.